# windows service command RPC error (sc.exe or psservice)

Tags: windows, windows-services

I am getting the following error when i try to run the command from remote machine

```
C:\>sc \\machinename query
[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 1722:

The RPC server is unavailable.
```

- I have admin privileges to that machine.

Any solution let me know.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I got this error because I was messed up the name of the server I was targeting. It will give you this error if you accidentally point it at nothing. In my case, the server name was a variable being defined from a text document so it took a while for me to realize.

Also noteworthy: There should actually be two slashes before the machine name (I'm sure it's just a typo, but just in case it could confuse anybody).

Comment: The original text of the question actually did have two backslashes, but Markdown was only showing one. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

The error 1722  is : The RPC server is unavailable. 
Verify if RPC service (Remote Procedure Call (RPC)) is running at remote machine with telnet, try at command line:
*>telnet your.server 135

If no errors occurs the RPC server is probably ok, than check system events for issues.

Comment: Good call, for me was Win FW blocking the port. Check via Powershell (PS 4 or newer): `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName MyTestserver.dom.com -Port 135 -InformationLevel Detailed`

Answer (score 3):

6 years later but anyaway.

Enable File and printer sharing on the remote computer and it will work.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323790

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my localmachine
[image: run SC QUERY on PCxxxx4]

I tested from another machine on the network
[image: run SC QUERY on PCxxxx0]

SC is nice..! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the Client DNS service is not stopped. This fixes the problem.